# How to split every pages of a pdf into multiple pdf files in C# (using iTextSharp)?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I am trying to convert every pages of a pdf into separate pdf files. I have given the range of 6 to create 6 separate pdf files.

```
using System;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Learning.SpitPdfApp {
    public partial class MainForm : Form {
        public MainForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SplitPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            MainForm objMainForm = new MainForm();
            objMainForm.ExtractPage(SourceTextBox.Text, DestinationTextBox.Text);
        }

        public void ExtractPage(string sourcePath, string outputPath) {
            int startPage = 1;
            PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(sourcePath+".pdf");
            int endPage = 6;
            Document objDocument = new Document(objReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));

            objDocument.Open();

            for (int index = startPage; index <= endPage; index++) {
                PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(objDocument, new FileStream(outputPath+""+index+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
                PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(objReader, index);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }
            objDocument.Close();
            objReader.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(@"Splitting successful!");
        }
    }
}
```

But it is throwing a *null reference pointer exception*. I can't figure out the problem i've caused.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 0):

This extracts page without any exception.

```
public void ExtractPage(string sourcePdfPath, string outputPdfPath, int pageNumber)
            {
                PdfReader reader = null;
                Document document = null;
                PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
                PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

                try
                {
                    // Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:
                    reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath);

                    // Capture the correct size and orientation for the page:
                    document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber));

                    // Initialize an instance of the PdfCopyClass with the source
                    // document and an output file stream:
                    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(document,
                        new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

                    document.Open();

                    // Extract the desired page number:
                    importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
                    pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
                    document.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating instance of same form to call ExtractPage Method? when you can call it without creating a new instance?

Here is a fix for your code:

```
private void SplitPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ExtractPage(SourceTextBox.Text, DestinationTextBox.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public void ExtractPage(string sourcePath, string outputPath)
        {
            int startPage = 1;
            int endPage = 6;

                for (int index = startPage; index <= endPage; index++)
                {

                    PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(sourcePath + ".pdf");
                    Document objDocument = new Document(objReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));

                    string destination = Path.Combine(outputPath, index + ".pdf");
                    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(objDocument, new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create));
                    objDocument.Open();

                    PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(objReader, index);
                    pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
                    objDocument.Close();
                    objReader.Close();
                }

            MessageBox.Show(@"Splitting successful!");
        }
```